# How to cast String from HQL query result to Date in ManagedBean

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

i have a table with 3 fields an integer a double and a date,when i query the table with hibernate and cast the results to the Type i want the string corresponding to the date doesn't get converted,so i am asking about a way to make this happen,here's the details:

the fields in my bean Recette.java:

```
private int id_recette;
private double montant;
private Date date;
```

the query and the casting:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dateM = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from 
Recette where date=:date");
            query.setParameter("date", formatter.format(dateM));

            Recette rc = (Recette) query.getSingleResult();//the line that throws the exception
```

the exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Date (java.lang.String and java.util.Date are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Replace `formatter.format(dateM)` with `dateM`. Your Recette.date property is of type Date and not a String, but you are passing a String. This is not a JSF related problem.

Comment: i do have a date in my database actually,are you saying that the cast from string to date can actually be done with the way i did it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassCastException: String can't be cast to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590036/java-lang-classcastexception-string-cant-be-cast-to-date)